# VS Code keeps telling me I don't have Python... but I do

Tags: python, installation, visual-studio-code, interpreter

this is a bit of a pain since I am very new to coding and this is a bit too much to understand right now.

So basically I have been using VSCode to learn to use python and a couple of days ago not only has it been telling me that it does not find a python interpreter despite me entering the path, but it also tells me that y haven't installed python altogether which is wrong since I have and it runs perfectly outside of VSCode.

I have tried uninstalling both VSCode and python and reinstalling them because I'm a noob and have no clue of what else to do- but to no avail. What can I do? thank you for all the help you can give me :)

Comment: What OS are you on and is python available from cmd or bash ?

Comment: In addition to Vijay's point: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. I am not sure what Vijay means, but I am using the latest version of python from the website

Comment: you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313903/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-to-find-python-3-interpreter-in-windows-10

Comment: Which website? How do you run python? I presume you aren't running Windows Subsystem for Linux...

Comment: I downloaded Python from python's own website- which was what that pesky notification in VSC led me to. other than that you should assume that I am running everything in the most beginner way possible off my laptop and with nothing particularly noteworthy. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: How the Python extension finds Python is [documented](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). You can also look in the Output Panel in the Python channel to see how the extension is running Python interpreters to try and figure out they are usable. We have seen issues where people have installed Python for a user that VS Code can't access (e.g. admin).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you check the following two aspects:

1. Python is successfully installed and interactive (cmd, input "python").
   Check that your Pythonpath is the current version of python, and if the path is an unloaded version, the interpreter will not be found.
2. Check whether the [python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) is successfully installed. It will look for the Python interpreter;
   If you uninstall and reload the python extension, you could try to restore the previous version;

In addition, if it still doesn't work, hopefully you could provide more information about error reporting so that we can solve your problem better.

Comment: thank you for your help! python is installed alright and I can use it on cmd, but I do not seem to have a pythonpath on my environment variables.

Comment: The "pythonpath" is in vscode. You could refer to: https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/python-path/

Comment: Is your problem solved? Marking useful answers will help others.

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately

Comment: @Juancasinisterra If convenient, please provide relevant configuration information and error log information for us to find out the issue in detail.