# Visual Studio Code wont find my interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have used python 3.8.5 before on this computer and one day it just can't find the interpreter. I've tried reinstalling python, reinstalling VS code, and I've tried repairing corrupt files.

Comment: What do you mean "won't find"? You can enter the path to the interpreter yourself. Does that not work?

Comment: are you on windows or mac or Linux??

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313903/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-to-find-python-3-interpreter-in-windows-10)

Comment: nope tried it nothing

Answer (score 0):

In vs code

- In top left, Click on **view**
- Click on **Command Palette**
- Click on **Python: Select Interpreter**
- Click on your python version

If python directory does not appear, copy **python.exe directory** and paste it in the **Python: Select Interpreter** bar.

Comment: when installing python, did u checked the option "add python to path"?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check whether it's a problem related to 'Python' which installed on your computer. Open the cmd out of VSCode, type in 'python --version' to check the output. If you can't get the proper output, you need to check whether you have added the python path to the 'PATH' system variable.

Second, if everything works well out of VSCode. That means that's the problem of 'Python' extension. You'd better reinstall or downgrade the 'Python' extension.